# E-mails not getting sent

Tags: php, html, email

I have a contact form, but the messages are not sending to the email I have declared. This is the `submit.php` file:

```
<?php

/* config start */

$emailAddress = 'xxxxxxx@hotmail.com';

/* config end */

require "../php/class.phpmailer.php";

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
        $_POST[$k] = stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

    $_POST[$k] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


$err = array();

if(!checkLen('name'))
    $err[] = 'The name field is too short or empty!';

if(!checkLen('email'))
    $err[] = 'The email field is too short or empty!';
elseif(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    $err[] = 'Your email is not valid!';

if(!checkLen('subject'))
    $err[] = 'You have not selected a subject!';

if(!checkLen('message'))
    $err[] = 'The message field is too short or empty!';

if((int)$_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['expect'])
    $err[] = 'The captcha code is wrong!';


if(count($err))
{
    if($_POST['ajax'])
    {
        echo '-1';
    }

    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        $_SESSION['errStr'] = implode('<br />', $err);
        $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    exit;
}

$msg =
'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
 IP:    '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "A new ".mb_strtolower($_POST['subject'])." from ".$_POST['name']." | contact form feedback";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();


unset($_SESSION['post']);

if($_POST['ajax'])
{
    echo '1';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['sent'] = 1;

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    exit;
}

function checkLen($str, $len = 2)
{
    return isset($_POST[$str]) && mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST[$str]), "utf-8") > $len;
}

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}

?>
```

If `submit.php` is opened in a browser, I get the following error message:

> **Warning**:  require(../php/class.phpmailer.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   **/home/content/96/9227096/html/submit.php** on line **10** 
>  **Fatal error**:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '../php/class.phpmailer.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   **/home/content/96/9227096/html/submit.php** on line **10**

I was also told by my hosting server that I might need to add the following relay server in my code:(but I don't know where)
`relay-hosting.secureserver.net`

Comment: The error pretty clearly states that it's failing to load the required PHP file (`../php/class.phpmailer.php`).  It's never even getting to the code which interacts with the email server.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `require "../php/class.phpmailer.php";` means that the `../php/class.phpmailer.php` file will be loaded and that if it can't be loaded then the script will terminate.

It is unable to load that script. That could be for any of a number of reasons.  Maybe it's not there. Maybe the path you provided is wrong. Maybe it's a file permission issue. You'll have to figure that part out.

But since it can't load it, the script terminates with the error message.

Comment: ok well the class.phpmailer.php is in a php folder and the submit is in another folder so I'm 100% sure the file path is correct. Could it be anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter similiar problems on some hosting providers. Even if the path was good require did not include file and terminated whole script. You could write there a real path to your file, and maybe that will help. Since this problem I started to use

```
require(getcwd().'actual/path/relevant/to/index.php');
```

and starder to write apps in one class, similiar to Java or C# desktop apps.